# why sequelize.sync() is not syncing the table unless i import the modals into the file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using postgres with sequelize. I'm trying to create a Products table in the database. On the main script file (app.js), i called the sequelize.sync() to synchronise the modal with the database. But, no matter how many times i tried, the table was not made in the database. The only query that was executed is this;

```
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
```

But, when i import a modal into the app.js file, the syncing occurs fine. I'm really confused by this behaviour.

These are my files;

**./utils/database.js**

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = new Sequelize("mydatabase", "myname", "mypassword", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "postgres",
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000,
  },
});
```

**./modals/product.js**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = require("../utils/database.js");

const Product = sequelize.define("Product", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  price: {
    type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
});

// export the Modal
module.exports = Product;
```

**./app.js**

```
const sequelize = require("./utils/database.js");

sequelize.sync()
  .then(() => {

    // listen
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log("Server running...");
    });

    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

The above code fails to sync. But if i import the modal into this file, it works fine.

```
const sequelize = require("./utils/database.js");

// importing Product modal
const Product = require("./models/product.js");

    
    sequelize.sync()
      .then(() => {
    
        // listen
        app.listen(3000, () => {
          console.log("Server running...");
        });
    
        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

Is it always needed to import all modals into the app.js file if want to use the sync() function?

Answer (score -1):

### Changing your file structure little bit, Try like below

./utils/database.js

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("mydatabase", "myname", "mypassword", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "postgres",
  operatorsAliases: false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000,
  },
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

./modals/product.js

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

const db = require("../utils/database.js");

const Product = db.sequelize.define("Product", {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    defaultValue: db.Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  title: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  price: {
    type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  imageUrl: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  description: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
});

// export the Modal
module.exports = Product;
```

Comment: Vague and doesn't provide an explanation, at all. Please be more thorough in your answer and make a point.